# Calendar UI not displaying properly

Tags: android, android-studio

CalendarView  not displaying properly when try to enter texts in EditText.
(softkeyboard opens , calendarview shrink)
How to set calendarView fixed height and width ?

Any custom library for Datepicker like ios ?

**Layout**

```
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <CalendarView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/im_date_edt"
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/im_date_edt"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_above="@+id/im_desc_edt"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/square_gray"
    android:padding="10dp"

    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/im_desc_edt"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/Description"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textColorHint="@color/md_grey_400"
    android:background="@drawable/square_gray"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Check the Image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `RelativeLayout` in a `ScrollView`.